# How to detect end of dialog in Webchat/DirectLine?

Tags: node.js, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I created a simple chatbot with botbuilder in Node.js. Due to the given environment I included the chatbot via a custom iframe. The frontend is WebChat with DirectLine.
How can I detect the end of the dialog in the parent window?

I could not find the correct way on how to catch the end of the dialog in the WebChat/DirectLine.

I render my chat with the following code inside the iframe:

```
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
 if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
  dispatch({
   type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
   payload: {
    name: 'webchat/join',
    value: { language: window.navigator.language }
   }
 });
}
 return next(action);
});

 window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
   directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: "thisismytoken" }),
   store,
   userID: '1',
   username: username,
   styleOptions: {
    botAvatarImage: "https://mylink.azurewebsites.net/avatar_user_1.png",
    userAvatarImage: "https://mylink.azurewebsites.net/avatar_user_1.png"
   }
 }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
```

In Node.JS I end the conversation with the following code:

```
            return await step.endDialog();
```

As soon as endDialog is run, I want to submit the parent of the iFrame. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish this requires only a few modifications to your code.

First, in your bot, send an activity just prior to the `step.endDialog()` call. This activity will be an event and will send data with a status to be picked up by your page.

In this example, I am including the user data so I can see who exited. I am also using the sendActivities() method so I can thank the user while simultaneously sending the event. You can, of course, just use sendActivity() to send the single event.

```js
  async finalStep(step) {
    const user = stepContext.context.activity.from;
    const data = { user: user, dialogStatus: 'complete' };

    await stepContext.context.sendActivities([
      { text: 'Thank you for visiting my bot!', type: 'message' },
      { name: 'data', type: 'event', channelData: { 'data': data } }
    ]);
    return await stepContext.endDialog();
  }
```

Next, in your page, use the `createStore()` method and check for the `action.type` of `DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY`. On any incoming activity, you will create a new Event called 'incomingActivity' which will take the received payload from the bot.

You will also add a `window.addEventListener` of the same name, 'incomingActivity', which will capture the incoming data and parse it, as needed.

Lastly, as you have already done in your code, pass the `store` into the renderWebChat component.

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => action => {
  if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {
    const event = new Event('incomingActivity');

    event.data = action.payload.activity;
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  return next( action );
} );

window.addEventListener('incomingActivity', ({ data }) => {
  const type = data.type;
  if (type === 'event' && data.channelData.data.dialogStatus) {
    const status = data.channelData.data.dialogStatus;
    const user = data.channelData.data.user;
    console.log(`User '${user.name}', with an id of '${user.id}', reached the end of the dialog`);
  }
})
```

Web Chat window:

[image]

Bot's console transcript logging:

[image]

Browser's developer console:

[image]

I use something like this fairly regularly so it *should* work for you.

Hope of help!